# Импорт данных из файлов на Python

Tags: python, telebot, telegram, python-import

Я пишу бота с помощью `pytelegrambotapi`, у меня есть два файла `main.py` и `command.py` я хотел импортировать команды с файла `command.py` в `main.py`; если просто импортировать код выдаёт ошибку:

> NameError: name 'bot' is not defined

а если я пишу переменную `bot = telebot.TeleBot(config.TOKEN)` в файл `command.py`, бот игнорирует импорт и не вызывает команды

*Command.py*

```
import telebot

@bot.message_handler(commands=['start'])
def start(message):
   bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Привет, я бот')

@bot.message_handler(content_types=['text'])
def send_text(message):
    if message.text.lower() == 'пинг':
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Понг')
```

*main.py*

```
import telebot
import config

bot = telebot.TeleBot(config.TOKEN)

@bot.message_handler(commands=['help'])
def start(message):
   bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Этот бот пока не предназначен что он будет делать')
   
if __name__ == "__main__":
    bot.polling(none_stop=True)
```

Comment: В command.py добавьте в начало `from main import bot`

Comment: @SergBocharov. Бот работает без ошибок , только проблема в том , что не запускаются команды из файла command.py

Comment: Это после добавления указанной мной строки? Вообще вам лучше перенести все функции в один файл, у вас всего две команды - зачем отдельный файл?